# how to use list function correctly

Tags: python, list, count

```
dnlist = ["Place 1","Place 2","Place 3"] 
polist = [] 
splist = [] 
dncount = 3 
count = 0 


def prices (): 
    while count <= dncount:
        print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
        print("Please enter the details for ",dnlist[count])
        print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
    #Ask for the dp
    try:
        sp = int(input("the dp is $"))
        print(sp)
    except ValueError:#Make sure they only input numbers
        print("Sorry, you must put number only.")
    splist.append(sp)


    #Ask for the po                
    try:
        po = int(input("the po is %"))
    except:
        print("Please enter a valid number.")

    #This is to ensure that the customer enters a reasonable percentage 
    if po <=10: print("Your percentage is too low. Please enter a higher percentage.") 
    if po >=95: print("Your percentage is too high. Please enter a lower percentage.") 
    polist.append(po)

prices()
```

This program works for Place 1 however, it does not move on asking the dp and po of Place 2 and Place 3

when I run the program, it does not stop asking for entering details for Place 1 but I want my program to work this way..

```
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Please enter the details for Place 1
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
the dp is $21
21
the po price is %34
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Please enter the details for  Place 2
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
the dp is $98
98
the po is %24
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Please enter the details for  Place 3
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
the dp is $109
109
the po is %87
```

Comment: Well, where do you increment count?

Comment: Your while loop condition is `while count <= dncount:`, but that never changes in the body of your while-loop. It is *always* `0 <= 3` == `True`

Comment: Put the whole code in `prices()` inside while loop and increment `count`

Comment: summarizing, check indentation and include an increment for `count`

Comment: what do you mean by increment count? how do you do that? it is my first year studying programming, please bare with me

Comment: imean  i just started this year but i have only been practising for a month

Answer (score 0):

Just a minor modified version to make it work. But it is not very good to use `count` in this way. Assign it to a variable inside your function would be better

```
dnlist = ["Place 1","Place 2","Place 3"]
polist = []
splist = []
dncount = 3
count = 0


def prices():
    while count <= dncount:
        print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
        print("Please enter the details for ",dnlist[count])
        print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
        #Ask for the dp
        try:
            sp = int(input("the dp is $"))
            print(sp)
        except ValueError:#Make sure they only input numbers
            print("Sorry, you must put number only.")
        splist.append(sp)


        #Ask for the po
        try:
            po = int(input("the po is %"))
        except:
            print("Please enter a valid number.")

        #This is to ensure that the customer enters a reasonable percentage
        if po <=10: print("Your percentage is too low. Please enter a higher percentage.")
        if po >=95: print("Your percentage is too high. Please enter a lower percentage.")
        polist.append(po)
        global count
        count += 1

prices()
```

second version to avoid warning of `count`

```
dnlist = ["Place 1","Place 2","Place 3"]
polist = []
splist = []
dncount = 3
count = 0


def prices(count):
    while count < dncount:
        print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
        print("Please enter the details for ",dnlist[count])
        print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
        #Ask for the dp
        try:
            sp = int(input("the dp is $"))
            print(sp)
        except ValueError:#Make sure they only input numbers
            print("Sorry, you must put number only.")
        splist.append(sp)


        #Ask for the po
        try:
            po = int(input("the po is %"))
        except:
            print("Please enter a valid number.")

        #This is to ensure that the customer enters a reasonable percentage
        if po <=10: print("Your percentage is too low. Please enter a higher percentage.")
        if po >=95: print("Your percentage is too high. Please enter a lower percentage.")
        count += 1

prices(count)
```

Comment: Thank you! :) @milo

Comment: Hi @milo , your suggestion works however, theres a syntax warning showing that the name count is used prior to global declaration?

Comment: yes. That's what I mean it is not good to use count like this. I have update a second version